# Retrieving member item from a queue?

Tags: c++, queue

I'm new to c++ so please bear with me if my terminology and knowledge is off.

I'm trying to print out or retrieve the string jobName after passing the JOB to a queue. In queue.h I have:

```
struct JOB {
  string jobName;
  int runtime;
};
```

In queue.cpp I am trying to write the appropriate method:

```
void Queue::display(){
  cout << frontPtr->job.jobName;
}
```

I'm completely clueless what to do. And yes, this is a small part of a school assignment. Right now, it says error: 'struct Queue::QueueNode' has no member named 'job'. So lost, please help.

Comment: What are you passing to the queue? Is it a variable/pointer/reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key will be in the definition of `struct Queue::QueueNode`.  Look there, and see what field it has that will give you a `struct JOB`.

Comment: AHH I just figured it out.. I needed
  cout << frontPtr->item.jobName;
instead. Thank y'all for the help. :)

Comment: @Heather: don't forget to say 'thank you' by upvoting and/or accepting the answer that helped you.